# Php ignores decimals while adding two numbers

Tags: php, decimal, price

When adding two number it ignores the decimals, in database the `product_price and product_shipping_cost` data type is `decimal(10,2)`

> $product_price = 272.70; $product_price = 189.00;
>   $product_shipping_cost 14.00;

The total should be `475.70` but i get `475.7` as the output how do i fix this i have tried adding `(float)` but still same

```
foreach($mycart as $row_checker){
    $CKItemSubtotal += (float)(($row_checker->product_discount>0) ? $row_checker->product_price * ((100-$row_checker->product_discount) / 100) * $row_checker->cart_qty : $row_checker->product_price * $row_checker->cart_qty) + $row_checker->product_shipping_cost;
}
```

Please can anyone help me

Comment: you can format your numbers using the php function `number_format()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php , php is removing any trailing zero, so if you want to have a formated "number" then you can do it with strings.

Comment: Don't user ternary operators for big lines

Comment: This does it thanks guys `number_format(round((float)$CKItemSubtotal,2),2)`

Comment: `number_format` will round the number for you. You can see this contribution in php docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#88424

Answer (score 1):

`number_format($number, 2)`

If two parameters are given, number will be formatted with decimals decimals with a dot (".") in front, and a comma (",") between every group of thousands.

Answer (score 1):

You may also format number using [`printf`](http://php.net/printf). In your case: `printf('%.2f', 475.7);`, but that's up to you.